# Xcode Interface Builder loading XIB file show view with transparency

Tags: xcode6, storyboard, interface-builder, xib

Something weird is happening with some of my `xib` files of my project.

I have one `xib` file where my view hierarchy not appear on live preview frame and those views appears with transparency.

See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

Now the most weirdest think, I can't restore other states of this same file in my source history, but Xcode loads this same file, from different history states exactly same like the screen shot above.

Maybe because I have two versions of this same xib, both is for different languages, anyway, the file is not same, each localised file are stored in different directories.

I'm just curious to know if someone got this problem before and if have some solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem.

This behaviour is default in Xcode, this means the views aren't installed for the current size classes on canvas.

I just changed to the size classes I defined before and looks fine now.